# Tagged VLAN with Procurve switch and RHEL is not working as expected

Tags: networking, redhat, vlan, hp-procurve

I want to configure tagged VLAN on RHEL6 where the ethernet switch involved is a ProCurve one. Now what I did is:

1. I created VLAN interfaces eth0.1001 and eth0.1002 on RHEL6 for server1 and VLAN interface eth0.1001 on RHEL6 in server2:

Server1:

```
vconfig add eth0 1001
ifconfig eth0.1001 192.168.199.199 netmask 255.255.0.0 up
vconfig add eth0 1002
ifconfig eth0.1002 192.168.198.198 netmask 255.255.0.0 up
```

Server2:

```
vconfig add eth0 1001
ifconfig eth0.1001 192.168.197.197 netmask 255.255.0.0 up
```

2. Created a tagged VLAN on the ProCurve switch:

   ```
    vlan 100
    tagged 9
    tagged 18
   ```
3. Run some traffic from server2 to server1:

   ```
    ping 192.168.199.199
   ```

   which was successful
4. Run some traffic from server2 to server1:

   ```
    ping 192.168.198.198
   ```

   which was successful again!!

On the other hand when I checked the port assignment for default vlan (ie 1). It shows both port 9 and 18 as untagged. And if I remove the VLANs from default VLAN then there is no traffic going on between the servers (even between the same VLAN interfaces ie eth0.1001). In this case changing the vlan from 'tagged' to 'untagged' again enables the traffic to go on.

Now I would like to know what am I doing wrong here. In my understanding, when two vlans are created in the OS and then traffic is send from one host to another that are part of the same VLAN, the driver will add the appropriate tags and when the packets reach the switch it will see the tags and appropriately move it to the right port. The examples available online show the configuration between two servers. I would like to know whether the same switch vlan tagging is also possible.

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of issues in your example.

First, since you are using a mask of `255.255.0.0`, all your IP addresses are on a single **Layer 3** network. Usually, a single Layer 3 network is associated with a single VLAN. It is possible that you are doing something else on your network such that this is valid but that isn't clear.

Second, the numbers used for the VLAN interfaces on your RHEL6 servers need to match the VLAN numbers used on the switch.

Assuming you are in a lab environment where you can make these changes, the following configuration should allow server1 to ping server2:

Server1: `vconfig add eth0 1001`

```
ifconfig eth0.1001 192.168.199.199 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
vconfig add eth0 1002
ifconfig eth0.1002 192.168.198.199 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

Server2: `vconfig add eth0 1001`

```
ifconfig eth0.1001 192.168.199.200 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

Created a tagged VLAN on the ProCurve switch:

```
vlan 1001 tagged 9,18
vlan 1002 tagged 9,18
```

The following should work:

Run some traffic from server2 to server1: `ping 192.168.199.199`

Run some traffic from server1 to server2: `ping 192.168.199.200`

The following should fail unless you have routing properly configured on the switch:

Run some traffic from server2 to server1: `ping 192.168.198.199`